# ¿Cómo puedo renombrar "student.txt" con el nombre que el usuario pone?

Tags: c++

Lo que quiero poner es que cuando el usuario ponga su nombre el archivo automáticamente se renombre de `student.txt` a `oliva_chen.txt`. Este código solicita la informacion y lo escribe a un archivo que se ha creado en el *código*.

```cpp
       // create string variables
       string fullName, major, hobby, work;

       //get input from user
       cout << "Name: ";
       getline(cin, fullName);
       cout << "Major: ";
       getline(cin, major);
       cout << "Hobby: ";
       getline(cin, hobby);
       cout << "Work: ";
       getline(cin, work);

       //open file
       ofstream file;
       file.open("student.txt");
       //write information to file

       cout << "The output file is named \"student.txt\"." << endl;

       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

En C++ tienes a tu disposición la función `rename` que hace justamente eso, renombrar archivos:

```
rename("student.txt", "oliva_chen.txt");
```

Nota que la función `rename` trabaja con `char*`, no con objetos de tipo `string`. Así que en tu caso también puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
std::string newFileName = "oliva_chen.txt";
rename("student.txt", newFileName.c_str());
```

Comment: La versión [tag:C++] de C++17 funciona con `std::path` que es construible desde `std::string`: [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename).